# Create a grpc server as non blocking

Tags: c++, grpc

I have a method `startServer()` which starts a simple cpp grpc server.

I want to make `server->Wait()` call non-blocking, without handling any extra overheads of maintaining the completion queue or handling RPC calls.

I dug around the async flavour of grpc server but did not find any simple example to do this without adding any extra overheads. Is there any easy/simple way to make this function non-blocking apart from running this on a separate thread?

```
void GrpcIface::startServer() {
    std::string address("0.0.0.0:5000");
    GrpcIface service;
    grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service);    
    std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "GrpcIface :: Server listening on port: " << address << std::endl;
    server->Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I dont think `Wait()` is mandatory. It at least does not look like it in the source [code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/28a0c0ff009b10d9f55a5fc48ff9ae8c24764d42/src/cpp/server/server_cc.cc#L1303). Or what do you mean by

> without handling any extra overheads of maintaining the completion queue or handling RPC calls.

?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to spawn a new thread for the Wait;

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> worker(new std::thread([&]
{
    server->Wait();
}));
```

When you want to exit, use this:

```
server->Shutdown();

if (worker->joinable())
{
    worker->join();
}
```